# Connecting to VLANs using Realtek NIC and software (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, networking, lan, vlan

i have two subnets using the same switch some computers acces subnet 1 and some other subnet 2.

I wanted to set up two virtual network adapter for each of the networks under Windows 8.1, i have Realtek 8111E NIC. I found a software called Realtek Ethernet Diagnostics Tool. in this software a was able to set VLAN adapters. I used Static IP adresses. but none of them could reach it's subnet :(

Answer (score 0):

For communication to occur between separate IP networks, you need a router.  Physical or virtual LAN, doesn't matter.  Something has to act as the router.  If it's a managed switch, you can probably set up routing in the switch.  Otherwise, you'll need to do so in one of the hosts on your network.

Comment: I do not want  communication between them for now, i just want them to be reachable :(

Answer (score 0):

You are not interested in Routing, you only want your PC to be able to communicate on either LAN via its own NIC. I have done this before and it works well. 
It sounds like you already successfully set up VLAN tagging in your NIC hardware, now you would need to make sure that your particular port on that switch is set for TRUNK mode, or Dot1Q, ISL, or Tagged, or Whatever terminology your particular switch uses for that. Also ensure that All of the VLANs that you want to access are all allowed on that trunk port. 
Based on the info you gave in your question, that is the ONLY thing you seem to be missing!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your gateways are not configured properly since static IP's should rule out a DHCP helper IP issue. You should have a default gateway for each subnet/VLAN. Also the port the PC is plugged into needs to be set to use the appropriate VLAN you want.